# Reference logical aggregates - CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a univerity assignment that consists in working with CQL and Cassandra.
In the first part of the assignment I have to "identify the
reference logical aggregates, thus providing a row-oriented view of schema information, and point out attributes which model relationships", but I don't understand what is a "reference logical aggregate".
The schema is the following (it's not created by me, I downloaded it with the assignment):

```
DROP KEYSPACE gameindustry;

CREATE KEYSPACE gameindustry WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

USE gameindustry;

CREATE TYPE fullname (
  firstname text,
  lastname text
);

CREATE TABLE games (
  name text PRIMARY KEY,
  description text,
  tags set<text>
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag text PRIMARY KEY,
  games set<text>
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  email text PRIMARY KEY,
  password text,
  name fullname,
  notes text,
  games set<text>
);

CREATE TABLE user_games (
  user text,
  game text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user, game)
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
  user text,
  friend text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user, friend)
);

CREATE TABLE matches (
  user text,
  game text,
  when timestamp,
  score int,
  PRIMARY KEY (game, when, user),
);
```

Comment: I have no idea what they are talking about, might be a good thing to ask professor or TA for clarification.  The term means nothing in C*. It maybe a term they are carrying over from your texts. This data model looks a bit like they are trying to use 3NF and associative tables like in a relational DB instead of denormalizing. Try to make it so each "question" has a table that can provide the answer in a single query, ie if you have to fetch a list of all the game ids for a user, then fetch all the games you've created a bad schema (it wont scale). Don't be afraid to duplicate data.

Comment: It does not look like the assignment is using de-normalisation that Cassandra is used for in the real world. I'd guess it is talking about values that are referred from other tables, though how is that useful on de-normalised data is a better question.